# Projectile Rotation in Unity3D

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, game-physics, projectile

I want to simulate a projectile motion. I use the following Code

```
 if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
        Rigidbody clone;
        clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position+ new Vector3(0f,0f,2f), transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
        clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * Speed);
    }
```

My projectile is a rigidbody and I want it to set its orientation like real projectile means when my projectile is about to collide with ground it should face ground not its launcher's rotation. it should change its rotation based on its speed. I don't know how to do that ?

Comment: Now it is working :) this line of code transform.LookAt(transform.position + rigidbody.velocity); solved my problem

Comment: you should answer your own question with above information, rather then commenting. It may help others by doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is working :) this line of code transform.LookAt(transform.position + rigidbody.velocity); solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself in the comment, just include `transform.LookAt(transform.position + rigidbody.velocity);` into the projectile controller update. Also make sure that you mark 'lock rotation' in rigidbody settings, because otherwise the physics system will try to rotate your rigidbody yourself and it may result in jittering, unrealistic behavior.